# how to block arp spoofing with arptables

Tags: linux, networking, iptables

Based on [this rules](https://superuser.com/a/1349985/886205), i am trying to block arp spoofing attack with "[arptables](https://linux.die.net/man/8/arptables)" from a ubuntu server that controls local network traffic, but my rule doesn't stop it

macs.txt contains the mac addresses of the computers on my local network that I must protect

```
192.168.1.10;14:cc:21:3a:YY:YY
192.168.1.11;14:cd:22:3b:XX:XX
```

Rule:

```
arptables -P INPUT DROP
for mac in $(awk -F";" '{print $2}' macs.txt); do
    arptables -A INPUT --source-mac $mac -j ACCEPT
done
arptables -A INPUT -j DROP
```

what's wrong? thk

Comment: `arptables` is used for ARP packet filtering. It won't help you to detect ARP spoofing. If you configure each hosts with proper arptables rules, then you can probably prevent an ARP spoof attack. `arptables -A INPUT --source 192.168.1.10 --source-mac 14:cc:21:3a:YY:YY -j ACCEPT`. Add rules for each trusted IP-MAC pair and do this on all hosts. In this way, the hosts will reject spoofed ARP packets.

Comment: @SouravGhosh I've already tested your rule and it works fine, but it doesn't stop netcut or tuxcut attack. (arptables doesn't even support LOG to see if it's really doing what it's supposed to do.)